# how to play audio using SFML in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, audio, sfml

I want to play audio using SFML and am trying to use the audio module.

All seem to work but I get this error message:`Failed to open sound file music.ogg (format not supported)`

Here is my current code:

```
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>

int main() {
  sf::Music music;
  if (!music.openFromFile("music.ogg"))
      return -1; // error
  music.play();
  system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Does the target computer have ogg codecs installed?

Comment: @user4581301 I don't think so. How do we install it to make the program run on any computer?

Comment: I believe they are an optional package for Windows 10, Web Media Extensions, but I haven't tested it out. I already have the codecs via WinAMP because I'm too damn old to learn a new media player.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because your operating system doesn´t support .ogg. by default, I think you should go to https://convertio.co/es/ogg-wav/. Then in the code, change the name of the file to the one you got with the wav convertor, and just move the file to the same directory in which you have your code :)